# "deepcopy" issues in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pass-by-reference, deep-copy

I was writing an AI solution to the TJ Wriggler problem and I'm having an issue that's causing my program to hang. I'm not exactly sure what it is since I should have more than enough memory to run the code. Rather, I think I'm changing a reference somewhere that I shouldn't be but I can't seem to figure out the exact place.

I'll run through execution up to the point where the program hangs:

First, the search function:

```
def BFTS(the_frontier):
    index = 0
    frontier = [the_frontier]
    while(True):
        if (not frontier):
            return None
        leaf = frontier.pop(0)
        if (leaf.GoalTest()):
            return leaf
        index = index + 1
        moves_list = leaf.FindMoves(index)
        while(len(moves_list) > 0):
            frontier.append(moves_list.pop(0))
```

This calls the FindMoves() function:

```
def FindMoves(self, current_index):
    moves_list = []
    for wriggler in self.State.Wrigglers:
        for seg in [wriggler.Head(), wriggler.Tail()]:
            is_head = {
                wriggler.Head() : True,
                wriggler.Tail() : False}[seg]
            for move in self.State.FindEmptySpaces(seg):
                if (move is not None):
                    moves_list.append(self.Move(wriggler.Index, 
                        is_head, move['x'], move['y'], current_index))
    return moves_list
```

FindEmptySpaces() finds all spaces that can be moved into and returns a list of dictionaries represent Cartesian coordinates. The FindMoves() function then calls the Move() function:

```
def Move(self, wriggler_id, is_head, new_x, new_y, current_index):
    head_or_tail = {True : 0, False : 1}[is_head]

    # Find action
    new_action = ("%s %s %s %s" % (wriggler_id, head_or_tail, new_x, new_y))

    new_node = self.CopyNode()
    new_index = current_index

    new_node.State.MoveWriggler(wriggler_id, new_y, new_x, is_head)
    return Node(new_node.State, new_action, new_index, self.Cost + Node.Step_Cost)
```

This function calls the CopyNode() function:

```
def CopyNode(self):
    # Create new Spaces List-of-List
    new_spaces = DataStructures.CopyListOfLists(self.State.Spaces)
    new_state = Board(new_spaces)

    # Create new List of Actions
    new_action = []
    for action in self.Action:
        new_action.append(action)

    # Create new Node
    return Node(new_state, new_action, self.Parent, self.Cost)
```

The CopyNode() function calls the CopyListOfLists() function:

```
def CopyListOfLists(the_list_of_list):
    new_list = []
    for lists in the_list_of_list:
        temp_list = []
        for items in lists:
            temp_list.append(items)
        new_list.append(temp_list)
    return new_list
```

As far as I can tell, the program hangs in the function CopyNode() but the strange thing is that it only does this on the second pass through Search_BFTS(). As I say, I probably changed a reference somewhere but I'm not experienced enough in Python to know for sure if this is the actual problem.

Any help that could be offered would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have accidentally created class attributes instead of instance attributes, would you? Any variables defined at class level are class attributes; instance attributes should be created in `__init__`.

Comment: `frontier` is never going to be equal to `None`. It's a list. Lists aren't `None`; lists are lists. If you want to check whether it's empty, you can use `if not frontier`.

Comment: `return moves_listmoves_list = []` - that isn't valid Python syntax. It looks like you accidentally mashed two lines together.

Comment: No, I have a few class attributes but only ones that should apply to all objects of the class created. Otherwise, the attributes are created in __init__

Comment: Is `SearchBFTS` supposed to modify the object passed in as `the_frontier`? It looks like you may have intended to make a copy.

Comment: Thanks user2357112, I misunderstood the None attribute and assumed that it would be equivalent to NULL in C++. As for the return, yes that was a copy issue.

Comment: originally the SearchBFTS function was defined recursively so yes, it was supposed to modify the_frontier.

Comment: Is `SearchBFTS` supposed to modify `index` anywhere? It looks like it might be intended to use a higher value for nodes deeper in the search.

Comment: originally, yes. The recursive definition of SearchBFTS took index as an argument and pass index + 1 when it recursed. It actually looks like I don't need it since I redefined it iteratively so I think I'll remove it.